# Spring AOP @Before in service - Before Advice check security

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

file applicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="employee" class="com.my.Employee">
</bean>
<bean id="observer" class="com.my.Observer" />
```

Employee.java

```
public Employee() {
    System.out.println("Employee constructor executed");
}

private String name;
private String company;

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(String company) {
    this.company = company;
}
```

Observer.java

```
@Before("execution(* com.my.*.get*()) ")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint jp) {
    Employee emp = (Employee) jp.getTarget();
    if("admin".equals(emp.getName())){
        // access method get*()
        }
    else {
        // can't access method get*()
    }
}
```

AOPTest.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "applicationContext.xml");
    Employee employee = (Employee) context.getBean("employee");
    employee.setName("admin");
    employee.setCompany("IBM");
    System.out.println("1 = "+employee.getName());
    System.out.println("2 = " + employee.getCompany());
}
```

If i change

```
employee.setName("user");
```

> > // can't access method get*(). But method getName() and getCompany() is still running.
> >     How can i control this. If setName("user")  >>> can't access to method getName and getCompany().
> >     Help me ! plz

Comment: Help me !...........

Comment: ... was there a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about throwing an `Exception` in `beforeAdvice`?

```
else {
   throw new NotAuthorizedException("Can not access to method get");
}
```

Comment: sorry, i have just updated my question.
Method beforeAdvice() don't have Exception

Comment: I think you did not get the point in my answer... what i understand from you question is, you dont want to allow call for get methods if user is NOT admin. So, simple way is to throw a RuntimeException in else and the subsequent calls will not happen.

Comment: ah, how can i get the error message, i want to show this for user.